# Printing to the console while still getting input

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I want to know if there is a way to, as the title says, console out on the lines next to the line that gets the input.

I want the console to look like this:

[image]

Using `cin` and then `cout` will only print after the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I want the text to be visible while typing.

I tried to search both on YouTube and StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Standard C++ console I/O is not this flexible. You need a library like ncurses, or direct platform-specific system calls, to accomplish this kind of thing.

Comment: It would be useful to show your code that does the incorrect behaviour.  Means the answer could just be a one line fixup to your reproducible example.

Comment: Depending on your platform, you may have access to `getpass` to do no-echo password entry.

Comment: You may be interested in ncurses, which helps to create visually stable outputs, and input fields at your console window in a portable manner.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you want to make something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string field = "#########\nPin", EndOfField = "\n#########", password = "";
char input = ':';
while (input != '\r')
{
    system("cls");
    if (input != '\b')
    {
        field += input;
        password += input;
    }
    else
    {
        field.erase(field.length() - 1);
        password.erase(password.length() - 1);
    }
    cout << field << EndOfField;
    input = _getch();
}
system("cls");
cout << "Password: " << password;
return 0;
}
```